# CSS backface-visibilty in IE 10 & 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Note that this works properly for all other browsers other than IE (I'm using 10&11). I am having an issue with a flipped object (`transition` and `preserve-3d` animation), where when flipped, it does not show and is transparent. `backface-visibility` is set to `hidden`. I have found a quick fix for this by taking out the `backface-visabiliy` style...

A good example can be tested on: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/
The author's code does not work properly in IE until you disable the `backface-visibility: hidden;` style.

Is it ok to do this here? It doesn't seem to break the ui in other browsers. Any other good explanation behind this - maybe just an IE glitch?